# what's the equivalent compiling options of ifort's "-double-size 128" in gfortran?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

I'm compiling some programs which was originally compiled by ifort with gFortran, and now rewriting the compiling command.

The original ifort compiling command was:

```
ifort -integer-size 64 -real-size 64 -double-size 128 fortran_code.f90
```

From that I write gFortran command in:

```
gfortran -fdefault-integer-8 -fdefault-real-8 fortran_code.f90
```

I can see that `-integer-size 64 -real-size 64` will become `-fdefault-integer-8 -fdefault-real-8` for gFortran but what does `-double-size 128` turn into?

Comment: Probably gfortran -fdefault-real-8 -freal-8-real-16 (you could use the sizeof(.) gnu extension to check.

Comment: @lastchance Why the latter? Why not `-freal-4-real-8` then as well?

Answer (score 1):

There is often no one-to-one map of similar compiler options. Also, you must be very careful and not apply these options mechanically. They have quite subtle but important consequences. You have to really read what they do in detail. They are described in the manual.

> *integer-size* This option specifies the default size (in bits) for integer and logical variables.

> *real-size* This option specifies the default size (in bits) for real and complex declarations, constants, functions, and intrinsics.
>
> For example, if real-size 64
> is specified, the CMPLX intrinsic will produce a result of type DOUBLE COMPLEX (COMPLEX(KIND=8)). To prevent this, you must explicitly declare any real argument to be REAL(KIND=4), and any complex argument to be COMPLEX(KIND=4).

That means that `DOUBLE PRECISION` and `DOUBLE COMPLEX` still remain what they were. The `-double-size` option will affect them. Also, be very careful to read the *whole* fine print. Think what will happen all those various declarations that you have in your code.

> *-fdefault-integer-8*
>
> Set the default integer and logical types to an 8 byte wide type. This option also affects the kind of integer constants like 42. Unlike *-finteger-4-integer-8*, it does not promote variables with explicit kind declaration.

> *-fdefault-real-8*
>
> Set the default real type to an 8 byte wide type. This option also affects the kind of non-double real constants like 1.0. **This option promotes the default width of DOUBLE PRECISION and double real constants like 1.d0 to 16 bytes if possible.** If -fdefault-double-8 is given along with fdefault-real-8, DOUBLE PRECISION and double real constants are not promoted. Unlike -freal-4-real-8, fdefault-real-8 does not promote variables with explicit kind declarations.

So gfortran promotes the default type but the `double precision` type is promoted with it as well.That makes a very good sense! The Fortran standard requires that `double precision` is larger than the default `real` and there are certain storage size requirements that should be fulfilled if the processor environment wants to be standard conforming.

---

There is another set of options that gfortran offers.

> -freal-4-real-8
> -freal-4-real-10
> -freal-4-real-16
> -freal-8-real-4
> -freal-8-real-10
> -freal-8-real-16

> Promote **all REAL(KIND=M) entities** to REAL(KIND=N) entities. If REAL(KIND=N) is unavailable, then an error will be issued. The -freal-4- flags also affect the default real kind and the -freal-8- flags also the double-precision real kind. ... These options should be used with care and may not be suitable for your codes. ...

These do NOT do the same as the former. The difference may be somewhat subtle to less experienced and it is really important to consider the details very carefully!

---

In the end you are likely to be fine with the set of options you use now. But you must really read the fine print and you really have to consider all declarations you have. Do you use:

```
REAL :: X
DOUBLE PRECISION :: Y
```

or

```
REAL*4 :: X
REAL*8 :: X
```

or

```
REAL(4) :: X
REAL(8) :: X
```

or the `SELECTED_REAL_KIND` or the kind constants from `iso_fortran_env` or `iso_c_binding`? These options affect these declarations in non-trivial ways and you have to consider each of these types of declarations separately.

Also, you must remember what various intrinsic functions will return and what arguments they require.

Comment: Using compiler options to change data type representations is just asking for a life full of pain. Fix the code, in the long run it will make your life much easier.

Comment: Yes, absolutely.